# ConnectedText reverse date topic presentation

Tags: date, datetime, wiki

In CT you can query and include date topics:

```
(($ASK [$Date>20160101]==summary|noedit))
```

This will add all date topics from 1 Jan and onwards to my current topic, however it always present them in descending order.

2016-01-01

2016-01-02

etc.

Is there some way in which you can reverse the order in which the topics are presented? With the latest presented first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have date topics in reverse or descending order ConnectedText version 6 or later is needed.

The date topics are then included as below:

```
(($ASK [$DATE>20160101]==Summary|noedit|descending))
```

CT version 6 has a number of switches available that wasn't available in version 4.